# CIImage filter is stretching my image vertically

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, uiimageview, core-image

I have an image which I'm using in a custom `UITableViewCell`. The image is a black triangle on a transparent background and I'm using a `CIColorInvert` filter to make it a white triangle on a transparent background.

The filtered (inverted) image is being stretched vertically, how can I stop this from happening?

If I load the `UIImage` directly without doing the filtering what I get is this:

[image: arrow ok, but black]

If I apply the `CIFilter` what I get is this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
// create the white triangle
CIImage *inputImage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:
                       [UIImage imageNamed:@"TriangleRight"]];

CIFilter *invertFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorInvert"];
[invertFilter setDefaults];
[invertFilter setValue: inputImage forKey: @"inputImage"];

CIImage *outputImage = [invertFilter valueForKey: @"outputImage"];

CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];

rightArrow = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[context createCGImage:outputImage fromRect:outputImage.extent]];
```

In both cases I'm setting the image in the `UIImageView` as follows:

```
cell.arrow.image = rightArrow;
```

The `UIImageView` dimensions are 15x15 (in IB). TriangleRight.png is 15x15 pixels, TriangleRight@2x.png is 30x30 pixels.

What am I missing to prevent the `CIFilter` from stretching the image?

**UPDATE:**
5 minutes after posting the question I figured out the problem: I'm using Auto Layout and the `UIImageView` didn't have an explicit height constraint (only width). Adding an explicit height constraint solved the problem. However, that still doesn't explain why using the `UIImage` directly worked (even without an explicit height constraint).

Answer (score 1):

```
UIImageOrientation originalOrientation = self->imageview.image.imageOrientation;
imageview.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:imgRef scale:1.0     orientation:originalOrientation];
```

Also, using the original orientation should have fixed it.