# iOS CIImage stretch the image

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, ciimage

Although I set my imageView as aspectFit, it seems that the image created via CIImage will always be scaled to fill.

A simple example of loading an image by 2 ways:

```
// 1. load directly via UIImage
UIImage *imageByUIImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Megan-Fox-Look.jpg"];
self.uiImageView.image = imageByUIImage;

// 2. load via CIImage
NSString *filePath =
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Megan-Fox-Look" ofType:@"jpg"];
CIImage *ciImage =
[CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
UIImage *imageByCIImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage scale:1.f orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
self.ciImageView.image = imageByCIImage;
```

The 2 image views (uiImageView and ciImageView) have same attribute of 'aspectFit' and same constraints of size (200x200). But only (1) display the image correctly , (2) stretch the image.

What's the problem? Thank you.

I create my project by Xcode 6.2

[image]

Comment: Don't worry about it. She looks pretty good either way.

Comment: Have you tried changing the image size.height property after you've constructed the UIImage? I realize that's not an answer, but is it a workaround?

Comment: Try giving height constraint to your imageview. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135216/ciimage-filter-is-stretching-my-image-vertically

Comment: @atulkhatri my image view have heigh constraint already

Comment: @1sand0s The images are both same size of 1280x779 when I debug.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this to load via CIImage:**

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"abcd" ofType:@"png"];
CIImage *ciImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]];
UIImage *imageByCIImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:ciImage scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageByCIImage.size);
[imageByCIImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,imageByCIImage.size.width,imageByCIImage.size.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
self.imageview.image = newImage;
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

The CIImage docs states that

> Although a CIImage object has image data associated with it, it is not an image

The stretching issue is probably related to the fact that the `UIImageView` will manage the actual rendering. And from other posts and playing around with CIFilters, it probably draws or renders with a CIContext using the view rect as the region, not the original image size.

The previous post solves the issue, and [this article](https://nshipster.com/image-resizing/) from Mattt mentions also an option seen in other posts : use a CGImageRef intermediary representation.

```
UIImage(cgImage: self.context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: outputImage.extent)!)
```